# How to propagate delegation token in Oozie ssh action

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I have an oozie shell action that executes a bunch of hadoop fs -get merge commands, it is currently failing because of:

[Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

In oozie docs it says how to do it for Java actions: here

IMPORTANT: In order for a Java action to succeed on a secure cluster, it must propagate the Hadoop delegation token like in the following code snippet (this is benign on non-secure clusters):

// propagate delegation related props from launcher job to MR job
if (System.getenv("HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION") != null) {
    jobConf.set("mapreduce.job.credentials.binary", System.getenv("HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION"));
}

How do I do this for Shell? when i try to echo $HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION, it returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using kinit command to authenticate using keytab in the shell script

```
 kinit ${kinit_url} -k -t <keytab>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop delegation tokens are copied to the local/current directory by Oozie. `export HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION=./container_tokens` should help.